# Why \(.) is used in section names in tex.web?

Tags: tex-core

Here are some examples of section names in tex.web:

```
@<Scan for \(m)\.{mu} units and |goto attach_fraction|@>
@<Adjust \(f)for the magnification ratio@>
@<Scan for \(a)all other units and adjust |cur_val| and |f| accordingly; |goto done| in the case of scaled points@>
```

Why `\(.)` is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a single use of `\(.)`, so I guess you are referring to letters enclosed in `\(` and `)` in general.

The answer can be found in the definition of `\(` at the beginning of `tex.web`:

```
 \def\(#1){} % this is used to make section names sort themselves better
```

E.g. if we would replace

```
@<Scan for \(a)all other units and adjust |cur_val| and |f| accordingly; |goto done| in the case of scaled points@>
@<Scan for \(m)\.{mu} units and |goto attach_fraction|@>
```

with

```
@<Scan for all other units and adjust |cur_val| and |f| accordingly; |goto done| in the case of scaled points@>
@<Scan for \.{mu} units and |goto attach_fraction|@>
```

and then tried to sort them, the `\.{` would probable sort before `all` and thertefore reverse the order. This is unexpected because the user only sees the following `mu` which would come after `all`, so `\(m)` and `\(a)` are introduced which explicitly mark which character should be used for sorting without having another effect.